# get controller's type information in middleware (or how to distinct request to web api and for a page)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-routing

I want to create middleware that handles exceptions but distinct requests to api controller and to razor pages / mvc. In middleware I have only a context.Request.Path url and want to "find" a controller (or page) who is assigned to process the request, then analyze the type information of it and make a decision.

Something like this:

```
MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware{
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
       try
       {
          await _next(context);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           var path = context.Request.Path;
           var isApiCall = ... ???? 
           if ( isApiCall   )
           {
              var json = GetJson(ex);
              wait context.Response.WriteAsync(json); // return json
           } 
           else {
              await _options.ExceptionHandler(context); // return the page
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is that it seems regular routing information  unavailable at this point. How to get the contoller's type info?

How to distinct calls to web api and for a page in context of middleware?

Comment: In Core both MVC and Api inherits from `Controller` ... fyi

Comment: I could use reflection api and check for controller's attributes (or derive from my own controllers).  But I'm welcome any alternative solution also.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this. You can use the built in [`UseExceptionHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-a-custom-exception-handling-page) middleware in Asp.Net Core and use it's `Path` property to get the route information probably like

```
var path = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>()?.Path;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check how feature works.
What is uclear? Why I want to send json with additionl information on error ? Have you tried use UseExceptionHandler()  to distinct api call and page calls? I failed. Anyway  UseExceptionHandler works in same context as custom middleware. There are no difference if custom middleware handles ms diagnostic - but there is full control of the code.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij No, I mean when there is already a ready one present then why  build a custom one? unless you are doing something extra which is note present

Comment: Answer is simple - I was failed with it, when was succeed with custom middleware (it works but "routing" distinction is hardcoded - and I want to avoid this). But I will give a second chance to standard  UseExceptionHandler. But in context of the question this is not important. UseExceptionHandler or custom middleware are just "frames" for the picture.

Comment: `var path = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>()` doesn't work in context of custom middleware. btw its path value is just  `context.Request.Path` not an iformation about contoller (ant its type)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472678/is-it-possible-to-use-useexceptionhandler-with-exceptionhandler-option-for-con this is the problem with the UseExceptionHandler()

Comment: Can we focus on the actual problem and someone suggest a way to find the type in the middleware? I don't care about exception handlers, I want to know how to do this specific thing